# How to use an instantiated object into a paramater for the method with use of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, instantiation

I'm finding it hard to use my methods even if I correctly instantiated my objects. Any ideas on where I went wrong?

example: I tried compiling the java file but the error I get is

"incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Books"

I think the problem is my instantiated object is being forced into a string but the problem is I used the correct syntax to call on a string. However, it still doesn't read it as a string and says that the instantiated object cannot be converted to the "Books" class.

I've already searched about it but all they say is the object hasn't been created. However, I checked my code and I already instantiated my object even before putting it into the method parameter.

I even tried to print the object on its own with the specific characteristics and it turned out fine. So I guess it goes right up until it gets put into a method.

One thing I don't understand is that I need that object to be referenced into a method.

Here is my code:

```java
class Books{
    String type;
    int pages;
    Books[] booklist;
    int bookcounter = 0;

    //Constructor to initialize the object "book"
    Books(int input){
        if(input == 1){
            this.type = "Math";
            this.pages = 5;
        }
        if(input == 2){
            this.type = "Physics";
            this.pages = 9;
        }
        if(input == 3){
            this.type = "Economics";
            this.pages = 20;

        }
    }

    //This method needs to add the instantiated object to the array list
    void addbooktype(Books kind){

    System.out.println("You chose: " + kind);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");        

    booklist[bookcounter++] = kind;
    }

    void printbooks(){
for(int i = 0; i <= bookcounter; i++){
    int y = i+1;
    System.out.println("Book #"+ y + "is: " +this.booklist[i].type);
    System.out.println("With pages of: " + this.booklist[i].pages);
                }
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bookchoice;
    int choice;
    String booktype;
    int booknum = 0;


    do{
        System.out.println("===========Menu===========");
        System.out.println("[1] - Pick a book \n[2] - Print book list\n[0] - Exit");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        switch(choice){
            //Selects and adds a book to the list
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Choose your book: ");
                bookchoice = sc.nextInt();

                Books book = new Books(bookchoice);
                System.out.println(book.type);

                booktype = book.type;

                book.addbooktype(booktype);

                booknum++;

                break;


            //Prints the book list
            case 2:
            System.out.println("List of Books: ");

            book.printbooks();
                break;

            case 0:
            System.out.println("Exit");
                return;

            default: System.out.println("Input not found.");

    }
    }while(choice!=0);

}
}
```

The errors I get is on the "book.addbooktype(booktype);"

This is where it bugs me, I printed the objected and even put it into a String container but it still rejects it. I don't know where I went wrong. And when it goes into the method it doesn't read the parameter. Any thoughts?

Comment: A class is supposed to represent something. Does your `Book` class represent a book, or a list of books?

Comment: What I intend to is it represents a list of books thats why I included a "Books[] booklist" array. Or is it wrong?

Comment: `Book.Type` is just String. You need to pass the object itself i.e `book` or change the method to accept `String`.

Comment: Then it should not have `type` and `pages` fields, because a list of books doesn't have a "type", nor does it have "pages". I think you need to rename this class to `BookList` and move `type` and `pages` into a new class `Book`.

Comment: @Goion How would I pass the object itself? I tried putting the "book.type" to the parameter in the method but it still puts up the same error.

Comment: @Sweeper Noted with the advice but wouldn't it still cause the same error? If i'll just change the naming conventions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a tutorial site or help/discussion forum***.  I fear you have some fundamental misunderstandings about some basic concepts, such as Classes, Types and Instances, and unfortunately SO is not really set up to be a tutorial "forum".
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: If this is for a class, I strongly suggest you review the class materials and talk to the instructor or teaching assistant (or your fellow students) to gain a better understanding of these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your method accepts Object of Class Book only. However when you are calling that function

```
book.addbooktype(booktype);
```

You are giving it type String (In your book class type is String variable). To fix that you either need to pass book object or change the method itself

**Passing the book object:**

```
Books book = new Books(bookchoice);
book.addbooktype(book);
```

and in function you can do something like this

```
void addbooktype(Books book) {

    System.out.println("You chose: " + book.type);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");

    booklist[bookcounter++] = book;
}
```

(Added Later) **Using This:**

This approach also utilizes the object however it is better than the approach described above. Instead of passing the object as a parameter which is redundant you can use java word `this`.

According to java docs [Using the this Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

So when you call function

```
book.addbooktype(book);
 ^   and          ^ are same
 |                |
```

Inside the method `addbooktype`

```
void addbooktype(Books book) {
   this and book would also be same. 
}
```

so instead you could do this

```
book.addbooktype();
```

and `addbooktype` would be

```
void addbooktype() {

    System.out.println("You chose: " + this.type);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");

    booklist[bookcounter++] = this;
}
```

An example where passing object and this would be useful is when you have to compare objects. Lets say you have two objects book1 and book2. You would do something like this

```
int compareResult = book1.compareTo(book2);
```

Your method would be

```
public int compareTo(Book book) {
   Now here this would be book1 
   and book would be book2

   Also keep in mind this.type would be same as type. type and this.type are both 
   referring to same object i.e who we called function on (book1).  
}
```

**Changing the function:**

or you can just change you function like this though I suggest you pass the object itself. If you just pass the String you won't be able to store it in `Books[] booklist`

```
void addbooktype(String type) {
    System.out.println("You chose: " + type);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");        

    // The line below will give error unless you change Books[] booklist;
    // to  String[] booklist;
    booklist[bookcounter++] = kind; 
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked up until the line where it adds to the array. It puts up the "String" cannot be converted to books but I think the value is already in the method it just rejects the addition of it into the array.

Comment: @Zidane101 I have update the answer to include your question.

Comment: @Zidane101 Idk why the comment was removed but the nullpointer was because your array `bookList` was never instantiated also I am going to make a change in my answer in a while please check it as well.

Comment: Thanks I kind of understood what your saying. I just thought that there should be parameters inside the methods thats why I was so fixated on putting some and forgot that it could have none. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your method addbooktype requires a parameter of Books type whereas you wanted a String parameter there

> void addbooktype(Books kind){

Your code would work if you would make this slight change:

> void addbooktype(String kind){

Edit: As per the comments, it seems I misunderstood the code. That being said, here's what you can do:

Replace

```
book.addbooktype(booktype);
```

with

```
book.addbooktype();
```

and replace

```
void addbooktype(Books kind){

    System.out.println("You chose: " + kind);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");        

    booklist[bookcounter++] = kind;
}
```

with

```
void addbooktype(){

    System.out.println("You chose: " + this.kind);
    System.out.println("Adding to the list...");        

    booklist[bookcounter++] = this;
}
```

This would add the currently calling object to your array and allow you to use it later.

Comment: But he is attempting to add it to an array of type `Book`, how would this fix his problem?  He really just needs 2 separate classes for the `list`, and for a _single_ `Book`.

Comment: That worked!! However, I'm confused isn't it that we should put the reference of the class instead of the data type? That's why I put up the class "Books" instead of a "string". I thought this conventions only for constructors not methods.

Comment: Hey, my previous solution would have worked but would have led to problems at a later stage. Try the solution after the edit. I'm using reference of the class in that solution.

Comment: Kind is not available as a field. May I suggest a new edit?